# Some sound may be a single tick sound from HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

In my PC I have an SSD and an HDD 2.5". This is an old 120GB Fujitsu Laptop HDD, more than 6 years old, but it has worked flawlessly and it still has excellent SMART parameters. Not a single reallocated sector ever. Normalized value is still 100 and threshold 24, actual 0.

There's nothing unusual about its performance. It is working fine. However I hear a single but clearly audible Click or Tick sound coming from my PC cabinet (and if I am not wrong it's coming from relatively the mid front part of the cabinet) and I suspect the only device that will make this 'Click' or 'Tick' sound is that HDD.

I have heard & I clearly remember a sound coming from my earlier Seagate HDD when it died. That was a sharp repeated 4-5 beats.

This is just a single Click or Tick and that too shortly after the PC is turned on. Later I don't hear anything. It has just started 2 - 3 days back, for past 6 years never heard of that sound from HDD.

In my Windows 7 OS, HDD is not set to any power saving mode. It never goes in standby mode as such.

What is technical explanation for a single Click sound coming from an HDD? 
Is this a possible indicator of an impending failure?
Are there any more troubleshooting options to try?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is just the sound of the hard drive head parking during periods of inactivity. So nothing to worry about; the head parks to prevent the disk being scratched in an impact or if the drive is jolted.

Comment: What puzzles me is that why does it happen a few minutes after starting the PC and thereafter it never makes any such sound?  What is so special or specific that happens a few minutes after booting into Windows that HDD makes a 'Click' sound.

Comment: I think I overlooked the fact it only happened once when I wrote this answer. However, it could be that some software is subsequently loading and keeping the disk awake the whole time. Or, it is happening but you just don't notice it due to other noise (like from games or something).

Comment: It's a clear single 'Click' sound that is sufficiently audible enough to make you conscious of it. So I am pretty sure if does not reoccur thereafter.